# Crash after dismissModalViewControllerAnimated on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4, presentmodalviewcontroller

I've encountered an unexpected problem with my iPad app and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or this is a normal device behavior -

1. `TableViewController` -> `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` -> `presentModalViewController`
2. Cancel/Save operation on `modalView` -> `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` -> works fine.

However -

1. `TableViewController` -> `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` -> `presentModalViewController`
2. Changing device orientation in 90 degrees (means, current view orientation is different than the parent view controller orientation
3. Cancel operation on `modalView` -> `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` -> CRASH

I've tried to modify the modal view when necessary using `setTranform` - it does change the view but doesn't change the `self.interfaceOrientation` value.

I believe the right way to resolve this problem is modifying `self.interfaceOrientation` value in 90 degrees but I don't really know how to do it - unless there is simpler solution.

---

Enclosed the debugging output - maybe it can help...

```
2011-11-29 11:09:35.981 myApp [65933:c203] -[UIDeviceWhiteColor count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7191bf0

2011-11-29 11:09:35.985 myApp [65933:c203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIDeviceWhiteColor count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7191bf0'

*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x011dc5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185    
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015f7313 objc_exception_throw + 44   
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x011de0bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0114d966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0114d522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   myApp                               0x0000eac4 -[myTableViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:] + 68
    6   UIKit                               0x005eb2b7 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 1834
    7   UIKit                               0x005ed8a4 -[UITableViewRowData rectForFooterInSection:] + 108
    8   UIKit                               0x005ed130 -[UITableViewRowData heightForTable] + 60
    9   UIKit                               0x004ada56 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateContentSize] + 333
    10  UIKit                               0x004a50c0 -[UITableView _rectChangedWithNewSize:oldSize:] + 559
    11  UIKit                               0x004a3917 -[UITableView setFrame:] + 266
    12  UIKit                               0x00463a03 -[UIView(Geometry) resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 385
    13  UIKit                               0x0046797b -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 273
    14  UIKit                               0x00463e94 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 497
    15  UIKit                               0x004de475 -[UIViewControllerWrapperView setFrame:] + 79
    16  UIKit                               0x00463a03 -[UIView(Geometry) resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 385
    17  UIKit                               0x0046797b -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 273
    18  UIKit                               0x00463e94 -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 497
    19  UIKit                               0x00463a03 -[UIView(Geometry) resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 385
    20  UIKit                               0x0046797b -[UIView(Geometry) resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 273
    21  UIKit                               0x004641c5 -[UIView(Geometry) setBounds:] + 623
    22  UIKit                               0x00601f51 -[UILayoutContainerView setBounds:] + 78
    23  UIKit                               0x004df4f7 -[UIViewController window:willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:] + 440
    24  UIKit                               0x0045655f -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 4347
    25  UIKit                               0x006dd619 -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:] + 1381
    26  UIKit                               0x004e3385 -[UIViewController _dismissModalViewControllerWithTransition:from:] + 2058
    27  UIKit                               0x004dfeb8 -[UIViewController dismissModalViewControllerWithTransition:] + 940
    28  myApp                               0x00014a04 -[myModalViewController cancelAdding:] + 132
    29  UIKit                               0x0042e4fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    30  UIKit                               0x004be799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    31  UIKit                               0x004c0c2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    32  UIKit                               0x004bf7d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    33  UIKit                               0x00452ded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    34  UIKit                               0x00433c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    35  UIKit                               0x00438f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    36  GraphicsServices                    0x02ce2992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x011bd944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x0111dcf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x0111af83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x0111a840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x0111a761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    42  GraphicsServices                    0x02ce11c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    43  GraphicsServices                    0x02ce1289 GSEventRun + 115
    44  UIKit                               0x0043cc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    45  myApp                               0x00001c5a main + 170
    46  myApp                               0x00001ba5 start + 53
)
```

terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c

My tableView numberOfRowsInSection:

```
return [iphoneWordPlistUnsorted count];
```

which is declared on .h file and allocated on viewWillAppear method:

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:WORDS_PLIST_IPHONE];
    self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 63;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 80;
}
else
{
    path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:WORDS_PLIST_IPAD];
    self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 94;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 120;
}

iphoneWordPlistUnsorted = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
iphoneWordsPlist = [iphoneWordPlistUnsorted sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

[iphoneWordPlistUnsorted removeAllObjects];
int i;
for (i=0; i < [iphoneWordsPlist count]; i++) {
    [iphoneWordPlistUnsorted addObject:[iphoneWordsPlist objectAtIndex:i]];
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Many thanks,

Dudi

Comment: What exactly is the crash, what exception does occur and what is the stack trace? Depending on the crash this might as well have to do with other thinks like memory management issues etc.

Comment: Hi,
This is the error I receive:


2011-11-29 09:09:25.337 [65805:c203] -[UITextRenderingAttributes count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x56339e0
2011-11-29 09:09:25.340 [65805:c203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextRenderingAttributes count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x56339e0'

It happens when I click the "Cancel/Save" buttons that call the dismissModalViewControllerAnimated.

Comment: Again - it doesn't happen it both views are on same orientation - only if they have a 90/270 degrees difference.

Thank you for your help

Comment: This sounds like a possible multithreading issue (thread-unsafe access of variables) or memory corruption. Have you run your app though instruments with NSZombieEnabled? It might be that the memory corruption does not provoke an error unless the rotation code has been run and moved some stuff around.

Comment: I added the debug output as an answer - maybe it can help...

Comment: Post your `-[myTableViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]` implementation.

Comment: posted now into my original question

Answer (score 0):

Your iphoneWordPlistUnsorted object is getting deallocated and the memory is getting reallocated as something else.  Running with zombies enabled (either in Xcode or in Instruments) will help you pinpoint the error.

Comment: OK I saw it. I had -     [iphoneWordPlistUnsorted release];
on viewwilldisappear method - could it be the reason for that?

Comment: Probably.  Run with zombies in Instruments to be sure.